# Orange and red circles in my finder document

Tags: finder, mojave

I have a macOS Mojave and I've just downloaded a PDF file from the internet. When I placed it in another folder, I found those two littles circles (one orange and another red).

What do they mean?

[image: finder window showing the circles]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are **Finder Tags**. Tags can have colours assigned and these show on the file in Finder when the file is tagged.

> *Remove tags from an item:* Control-click the item or tap it with two fingers, then click Tags. Select the tags you want to remove, then press Delete.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp15236/mac